# Asp.net :Getting selected value from dropdown in .cs file

Tags: asp.net

I want to get selected value of drop down and i cant make control runat="server"

```
  <form id="form" action="Default.aspx" method="post">       
 <table>
   <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td align="left" >
   <select id="formsSelect" style="font-family: arial,sans-serif;font-size:10px;>      
  <%
  for (int x = 0; x < forms.Count; x++)
  {
  %>
      <option><%= forms[x].ToString() %></option>        
 <%
  }
 %>
</select>

<input  type="submit" name="formType" value="Search" style="color: #000000;"/> 
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

any help

Comment: on the same page or on Default.aspx ?

Comment: Why don't you use ASP.Net dropdown control?

Comment: @WaqarJanjua yes on same page

Comment: did you find the solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not get html control value in codebehind ,you should use asp:DropDownList control,then you will get

```
    protected void Dropdown_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
     string val= Dropdown.SelectedValue.tostring();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript you can get it as

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var ddl = document.getElementByID('formsSelect');
   // The value is persent in ddl, you can use it as
   var selectedvalue= ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].value; 
</script>
```

Comment: how i can get var selectedvalue in .cs page ??